# How to send error in laravel response?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am writing a code for changing password. My code is as follows:

```
public function changePassword(ChangePasswordRequest $request)
{

     $credentials = ['email'=>Auth::user()->email, 'password'=>$request['old_password']];

    if (Auth::validate($credentials))
    {
        password change code;
    }
    else
    {
        What should be there?
    }
}
```

Without using ajax we can return redirect to view with errors.
What should be the error sending code in else part when using ajax, if the old password is wrong? Can we match old password in ChangePasswordRequest.php as well?

Comment: Maybe `403 Forbidden`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return response()->json(['old_password'=> ["Your old password is not correct."] ], 403);
```